# Freedom fighters vs Freedom fighters

Tags: word-choice

Freedom fighters fight **for** freedom. Fire fighters fight **against** fire. I want to write an article comparing people who fight for freedom versus people who fight **against**  freedom. Would *"Freedom fighters vs Freedom fighters"* be a wrong title ?

Comment: Related: [How to determine if an “X fighter” fights for or against X?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/10630/how-to-determine-if-a-something-fighter-fights-for-or-against-something)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Freedom Fighters vs Freedom Fighters* is an excellent title. The auto-antonymous property of the phrase *Freedom Fighter*, whether obvious or not, immediately arrests the interest of the reader, urging them to read on.

Comment: Kinda like "_Spy vs. Spy_!"

Answer (score 10):

Perhaps an alternative would be to refer to the action rather than the people:

> **Freedom fighting vs. Fighting freedom**

This has the advantage (perhaps *disadvantage* if your intention is to force people to start reading the article) that it can probably be interpreted correctly on its own, whereas "Freedom fighters vs. Freedom fighters" is snappy but has no clear meaning*. It also retains some of the snappiness (at least, balance and alliteration) of the original. Unfortunately, *freedom fighting* sounds a little odd to me, so I don't find my suggestion entirely satisfactory.

<sub>* Without context I would interpret it as being an article about in-fighting within the <s>rebel alliance</s> freedom fighters' group.</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Very well written. A title that will catch the eye. If however, you are looking for alternatives:

> Freedom Fighter vs. Freedom Buckers

Buckers meaning : Informal : To resist or oppose obstinately; object strongly: i.e. *The mayor bucked at the school board's suggestion.*

Just another suggestion:

> Freedom Fighter vs. Liberty Terminators.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer and for the nice suggestions :)

Answer (score 1):

"Freedom Fighters vs. Fighters of Freedom"?